# Problem with navigating fragments when i press on back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onbackpressed

Have a fragment in which I display the `recyclerView` list. 
When I click on a list item in `MainActivity` I call the method:

```
fun FragmentActivity?.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment): Boolean {
    if (this == null) return false
    try {
        supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(
            R.id.container, fragment,
            fragment.createTagName()
        )?.commit()
    } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

After this I press the system back button and I have a duplicate list.

Also i have in my `MainActivity` next fun:

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        val onBackPressListener = currentFragmentInContainer() as? OnBackPressListener
        if (onBackPressListener?.onBackPress() != true) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have not added the current fragment to the back stack. 
In order to get to the starting point, you have to mark the fragment. `addToBackStack(tag:String)` will help you to do that.

Code:

```
fun FragmentActivity?.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment): Boolean {
    if (this == null) return false
    try {
        supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(
            R.id.container, fragment,
            fragment.createTagName()
        ).addToBackStack(fragment.createTagName())?.commit()
    } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is the documentation about the method : [addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addtobackstack)

Comment: Problem is not resolved(
Maybe here the problem is also in the data
but I can't say for sure yet